# motivation when working with smarter people

Tags: work-experience

What do you do when you work with smarter people? What if you do things slower and have to recover by working from home?

Does it make sense to change the job, even if the people are always very nice and there are no stressful deadlines?

Comment: Could you add some more details?  Like what are you recovering from?  Are these smarter individuals actively doing things that are hurting your motivation, or is it coming from your own self-esteem?

Comment: Also are you experiencing [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)?

Comment: If people around you are both smart and nice and,  apparently, your environment is not cut-throat,  then why are you feeling that much stress?

Comment: Don't mistake experience for smartness.

Comment: That's great! I live by the motto "if you are the smartest person in the room you are in the wrong room". It seems it applies to your case.

Comment: Do you finish the task that are given to you in time ? If so nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have plenty of experience working with smarter people, including geniuses.

1. I love picking their brains. Except when they can't communicate anything if their lives depended on it. I've run into really bright people and geniuses whose ability to explain anything they figured out let alone teach it was near zero. To the pent-up frustration of all sides.
2. Perseverance. I've beaten really bright people and geniuses because they wouldn't admit to their mistakes and thus learned nothing from the mistakes they made, who lacked perseverance - we or at least I complain that software developers are none too bright as a group but I know why: it's because to go through the learning curve and become a software engineer, the top predictor that you will be successful at going through your learning curve is your level of persistence with your brains being a distinct second or third. If you don't give up, you keep hammering at it and you try a variety of approaches until you find approaches that work for you, you will succeed in becoming a software developer and in getting a job as one.
3. Determination. I was not going to let myself getting trashed, being soundly, emphatically, humiliatingly being beaten be the final word on my condition if the stakes were high enough. The really bright people and the geniuses whom I beat did not act like me. They acted like - well, people - and let themselves become discouraged and stay discouraged.
4. Guts. It takes a certain amount of guts to admit that you have limitations and still go for it. Really bright people and geniuses have fewer limitations to worry about, but they probably feel more of the pain when they run into their limitations. And at least some really bright people and geniuses become disoriented, discomfited and stalled - they just don't know how to cope.
5. Confidence. You have to have confidence in your abilities and your qualities. Having confidence allows you to recover from setbacks, pivot from them, work out what went wrong and double down and move forward. Really bright people and geniuses can have confidence issues, just like - well, people.
6. Geniuses can figure out 4 a lot faster than I can put 2 and 2 together. At the end of the day, it doesn't matter because I have figured out 4, too. It took me longer, so what?
7. You are who you work with. You can't put in 8 to 12 hours a day and claim that they don't affect you. If you work with idiots, you'll turn yourself into one. If you work with smarter people, you'll turn yourself into one of them. Because that's what it takes to survive in their environment. I decided a long time ago that I am better off working with really bright people and geniuses - to learn is to live. And you start dying when you are not learning. There is a Vietnamese proverb to the effect that it's preferable to be the student of a great teacher than to be teacher to a bunch of idiots.

And remember that really bright people and geniuses are not super humans - they have to go to the bathroom, they get sick and they feel pain and fear just like everyone else.

Having said that, I still remember by name those really bright people and geniuses who matched me quality for quality, and I still remember them with respect and awe decades after our life paths forked. They deserve every bit of the career success they have. And no, I never beat them because they never allowed themselves to be caught with their pants down by me or anyone. I can live with that :) And I have to say, having a chance to work with them was a stroke of good luck and working with them was a pleasure.

Comment: I learned a while back that I'm a pretty mediocre engineer. But damn if I'm not going to be the best mediocre engineer I can be, and learn from all the better engineers around me :) +1 for an awesome answer.

Comment: indeed, thanks a lot for this answer and everyone else for other answers. It helps to boost self-confidence.

Answer (score 7):

I have worked with people who are just as smart as I am. That was a really nice experience, because lots of things happened without me having to do them!

I also worked from time to time with people who were smarter than I. That is usually a good experience, because it is challenging, and you can learn a lot if you handle it right.

There is no need to worry if you are slower than someone who is outstandingly good. And certainly no need to work overtime and/or taking work home with you because you are slower. It is most likely that you are just as good or better as anyone else your boss could hire, because outstanding people are *rare*. That outstanding person is also probably paid more than you are, because they are more valuable to the company. There is no need to be as good as a one-in-a-hundred person.

Comment: I also worked with people who were as smart as I am and at times it was exhausting and frustrating because they felt their intelligence was a valid excuse for poor social behaviour, especially towards juniors and minorities. Now I value friendly, fair, and level-headed people at least as highly as smart people ;)

Comment: I suppose I count "social behaviour" as part of smartness. So a highly intelligent asshole wouldn't rank _that_ high on _my_ smartness scale.

Answer (score 4):

For a start do something with your self esteem.

They have employed you. They think you are smart enough.

If you have just started a job then of course you will do things slower. This is expected.

Just enjoy the new experience and learning stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem. They may not be smarter, just more efficient, I've worked with and compete against people who may be smarter than me, but experience, work ethic and efficiency make me look far superior.

But even if they are smarter, so what?

As long as you are able to do your tasks that is all that matters. You do the best you can with what you have, nothing to be ashamed of so long as you're doing your best.